# Find the minimum value of $\frac ab+\frac {b}{a+b+1}+\frac {b+1}{a}$ when $a,b>0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math

I was trying to solve this question and I observed that if I use partial derivative then it would be calculating. Moreover, I observed that $\frac ab\times\frac {b}{a+b+1}\times\frac {b+1}{a}=\frac {b+1}{a+b+1}$. So I thought to use AM-GM inequality and got

$3(\frac {b+1}{a+b+1})^\frac13 \leq \frac ab+\frac {b}{a+b+1}+\frac {b+1}{a}$.

Now the equality holds if $\frac ab=\frac {b}{a+b+1}=\frac {b+1}{a}$.
From here I also got these relations $\frac {b+1}{a+b+1}=\frac a{a+b}$ and $\frac ab=\frac {b}{a+b+1}=\frac {b+1}{a}=\frac {a+b+1}{a+b}$. I am hoping that I will get a finite expression of $(\frac {b+1}{a+b+1})^\frac13 $ and then we are done as the particular values of $a,b$ are not asked.

Help me from here. Am I in the correct way? Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Let $b = 1$ and $a \to -\infty$, and we have that the expression $\to -\infty$ as well. I presume you miss out some restrictions on what $a,b$ can be?

Comment: @ClementYung, I think he is taking $a,b>0$

Comment: I think min value is $\frac{\sqrt{13+16\sqrt 2}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \approx 2.4844$ for $a,b > 0$

Comment: Yes, I am sorry.

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG You can include your answer as well. I will be happy to see your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a>0$ and $b>0$ let $1=t$ and $f(t)=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a+b+t}+\frac{b+t}{a},$ where $t\geq0.$

Thus, $f'(t)=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{b}{(a+b+t)^2}>0,$ which says $$f(t)\geq f(0)=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a}.$$
Now, let $a=bx$, where $x>0$.

Thus, we need to find $\min\limits_{x>0}g,$ where $$g(x)=x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}.$$
But $$g'(x)=1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x^4+2x^3-x^2-2x-1}{x^2(x+1)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{(x^2+x-1)^2-2}{x^2(x+1)^2}=\frac{(x^2+x-1-\sqrt2)(x^2+x+\sqrt2-1)}{x^2(x+1)^2},$$ which gives $$x_{min}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5+4\sqrt2}}{2}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got that the infimum is equal to $$\frac{2\sqrt{10+8\sqrt2}-\sqrt{5+4\sqrt2}-1}{2}=\frac{(2\sqrt2-1)\sqrt{5+4\sqrt2}-1}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(9-4\sqrt2)(5+4\sqrt2)}-1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{13+16\sqrt2}-1}{2}\approx2.4844...$$

We can use also the following reasoning.

Let $a=bx$.

Thus, $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a+b+1}+\frac{b+1}{a}=x+\frac{b}{bx+b+1}+\frac{b+1}{bx}=$$
$$=x+\frac{1}{x+1+\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{bx}>x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}$$ because
$$x+\frac{1}{x+1+\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{bx}-\left(x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{bx}-\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1+\frac{1}{b}}\right)=\frac{1}{bx}-\frac{\frac{1}{b}}{(x+1)\left(x+1+\frac{1}{b}\right)}>0.$$
Id est, it's enough to find an infimum of $x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}$ and the rest is the same.

We see the for $b\rightarrow+\infty$ the expression $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a+b+1}+\frac{b+1}{a}$ is closed to $x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}$, which says that $$\inf_{a>0,b>0}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a+b+1}+\frac{b+1}{a}\right)=\inf_{x>0}\left(x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{13+16\sqrt2}-1}{2}.$$

Comment: Here $1>0$ so $f(1) >f(0)$. How do you know that the min value will be at the min value of $f(0)$?

Next vital question, how did you think of an answer like this?

Comment: @Ri-Li I chose this form of the explanation because I think that it's nice. You can get the same result for $a\rightarrow+\infty$ and $b\rightarrow+\infty$. In this case $1$ is not relevant. But I think it's better see please better my solution. I proved that $\inf f=2.48444...$ and since $f$ is homogeneous already we can assume that $t=1$, which gives your starting problem.

Comment: And why will the infimum be attained at $f(0)$? From your solution, we get $f(1)>f(0)$.

Comment: @Ri-L because $f$ increases.We proved it! $f'(t)>0$.

Comment: Yea but the infimum might be at $f(.9)$. See you have considered t=1 and then t as a variable like t>0. Now infimum should attained in the neighborhood of 1 right!! I am bit lost there. May be you can add some details. You have chosen a constant =variable and then you are saying that the min value when t=1 is same as minimum value when t=0??

Comment: @Ri-Li I added something. See now.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks a lot. I didn't think I could get it by myself . You are genius.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks a lot. I didn't think I could get it by myself . You are genius.